# Visual Recognition Error when creating credentials

Tags: ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I am trying to create credentials for a bound VR service.

> Service broker error: {"description"=>"Only one free key is allowed per account in a 24-hour period."}

I am not using any other VR/AlchemyAPI service. Only some days ago I used another app with another VR instance, but that one was deleted a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can use the service.

1. Leave it the service as unbind and use the apikey directly in your app.
2. Or, delete current default credential (because only one Watson apikey is allowed in a org, and bind will try to create new credentials)

   ```
   cf service-keys SERVICENAME  (check service-key name, it may be Crendentials-1)
   cf delete-service-key SERVICENAME Credentials-1
   cf service-keys SERVICENAME    (verify wether it is deleted)
   cf bind-service APPNAME SERVICENAME
   cf restage <APPNAME>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As Pang says, one way of working around the limitation in the free tier is to leave the service unbound and not use the Bluemix service binding. One way to do this without hardcoding the keys is to add the following to the deploy step (assuming the service instance has the name "Visual Recognition"):

```
  VIS_REC_API_KEY=`cf service-key "Visual Recognition" "Credentials-1" | sed -En 's/.*api_key.*"(.*)".*/\1/p'`
  cf set-env "${CF_APP}" VIS_REC_API_KEY ${VIS_REC_API_KEY}
```